# Where do I include custom JS and CSS files in Laravel 9?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, laravel-9

I'm manually downloading these CSS and JS files from: https://github.com/1j01/os-gui

I'm not sure where in my Laravel 9 app I should place the CSS and JS files.

What's the proper way to do it? Should I just download and place the files in the `public` directory? But shouldn't I be utilizing Laravel 9's Mix to compile the JS CSS files, and if so how can I go about doing that?

This is the list of files I want to use:

```
css/layout.css
css/windows-98.css
css/windows-default.css
js/$Window.js
js/MenuBar.js
js/parse-theme.js
js/demo.js
js/jquery-3.3.1.js // i'll probably use v3.6.0 (or whatever is the latest version)
```

Comment: I usually place them inside of the public folder i create a assets directory that contains the js and css files but you can also place them inside of resources/assets directory as well. I believe laravel comes built in with those directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those files to be optimized and controlled and also want that every request does not download a bunch of css and js files, you should use laravel mix which is installed by default

You should put those files inside /resources folder and compile them into a single file, adittionally you could purge with the [mix purge plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-purgecss) so your assets will be purged/optimized.

This is really simple in your webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .css('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        // and in your app.css you can @import every css you need to load 
    ]);
```

Comment: When I placed the files inside of ```resources/js/os-gui``` and ```resources/css/os-gui``` and I ran ```npm run dev```, the two files ```app.js``` and ```app.css``` were the only ones compiled ```608 KiB``` and ```1 bytes``` respectively (obviously the file sizes are too low, which hints to the fact that the ```os-gui``` js and CSS files weren't compiled). Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From mix example usage you have to tell mix what to compile.
`/* src/app.css */

@import 'layout.css';
@import 'windows-98.css';
@import 'windows-default.css';


body {
    color: red;
}` https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs